# Receiver for Android App info activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way to create a BroadcastReceiver that can be fired when user goes to App info activity (Settings > Application Management > Pick an app)? If so, will we know which app's info is showing up?

Thanks,
hmlaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no broadcast which is fired when user opens a particular activity.

If you want to know the activity which the user is currently on, you can try to periodically check the activity stack to know which activity the user is currently viewing.

```
while(true) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    String pkg = runTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName(); 
    String activity = runTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
    String tmp = pkg + " : " + activity;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Run this in a thread and it will wake up every 1 second and give you the activity which is currently on the screen. Compare it with activity you are looking for to know when the user calls it.

Comment: I asume that every App Info screen is the same Activity. So you still won't know the app that is selected.

Comment: The questioner was looking to find a broadcast for user going to the app info activity. Since that is not possible, I just tried to give a workaround for that part of the question. As for the second part, I agree that App Info screen will be one activity. The questioner wanted to know if he could get the activity, will it tell him which app info is being viewed. In my limited knowledge, the answer is no

Comment: I agree with you, maybe it's possible to read out the title of the Activity. Which gives some what info.

Comment: If you run the code given above, the String activity variable will have the name of the activity which is shown on the screen (polled every 1 second)

Comment: @Sirkant: I already tried that, unfortunately class name of all second tier setting activities is the same.

Comment: Same activity can be used to show different content. Consider an activity which is a menu to show various text. Example "one", "two", "three". Another activity with a text field. What is shown in the text field can be changed according to the selection of menu in the previous activity. The menu activity will start the new text field activity with an intent with the text to display added in the intent. The text field activity will thus show different values depending on the menu selection. The activity name will not give the content/objects of the activity

Comment: That's true. That's why I think unfortunately above solution will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `Intent` broadcasted.

(Also why do you want this information?)

If you want to know when an user removes your app: listen to the [PACKAGE_REMOVED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) `intent`.

Comment: As a requirement I would like to send a notification (to the admin) if user decides to force stop or uninstall my app.

Comment: Force stop is highly debatable. Android will kill the app if it needs resources. So when do you draw the line between user initiated stop or by OS? The outcome is the same.

Comment: Uninstall app you can listen to PACKAGE_RMOEVED (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED).

Comment: My app is a device admin so it cannot be (easily) uninstalled. Problem with Force stop is that it kills all of the services and even broadcast receivers.